# Div height on mobile chrome

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, mobile, height

Can anyone tell me why this

http://ladylena.co.uk/test_scene.html works fine in Chrome on Mobile (full size)

But this http://ladylena.co.uk/test_guide.html only shows in a small box top left?

I think they're loading the same way.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot. Also, search if it has to do with setting the page to handheld (using the appropriate media meta tag option).

Answer (score 0):

Found problem in CSS where there was a conflict with bootstrap